# Finding corresponding vertex from 3d to 2d

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, computational-geometry

I have this simple 3d data points:

```
v = {{0.`, 0.016821`, -0.5`}, {0.353553`, -0.75`, -0.353553`}, {0.`, -0.75`, -0.5`},
    {0.353553`,  -0.013361`, -0.353553`}, {0.5`, -0.75`, 
   0.`}, {0.5`, -0.020719`, 0.`}, {0.353553`, -0.020719`, 
    0.353553`}, {0.353553`, -0.75`, 0.353553`}, {0.`, -0.020719`, 
    0.5`}, {0.`, -0.75`, 0.5`}, {-0.353553`, -0.020719`, 
    0.353553`}, {-0.353553`, -0.75`, 0.353553`}, {-0.5`, -0.020719`, 
    0.`}, {-0.5`, -0.75`, 0.`}, {-0.353553`, -0.043838`, -0.353553`}, {-0.353553`, 
    -0.75`, -0.353553`}};
```

and

```
 polys = {{2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 1}, {5, 2, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {8, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 8}, 
          {10, 8,  7}, {7, 9, 10}, {12, 10, 9}, {9, 11, 12}, {14, 12, 
          11}, {11, 13, 14}, {1, 3, 15}, {15, 3, 16}, {14, 13, 15}, {16, 14, 15}};
```

Same data, in 2d representation: following are 2d points

```
 uv = {{0.2505`, 0.500001`}, {0.2505`, 0.624988`}, {0.009907`, 
     0.500001`}, {0.00005`, 0.624988`}, {0.2505`, 
     0.375013`}, {0.012311`, 0.375013`}, {0.2505`, 
     0.250026`}, {0.012311`, 0.250025`}, {0.2505`, 
    0.125038`}, {0.012311`, 0.125038`}, {0.2505`, 
    0.00005`}, {0.012311`, 0.00005`}, {0.2505`, 0.874962`}, {0.2505`, 
    0.99995`}, {0.012312`, 0.99995`}, {0.012312`, 
    0.874963`}, {0.019862`, 0.749975`}, {0.2505`, 0.749975`}};
```

and

```
 npolys = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {5, 1, 6}, {1, 3, 6}, {7, 5, 6}, {6, 
           8, 7}, {9, 7, 8}, {8, 10, 9}, {11, 9, 10}, {10, 12, 11}, {13, 14, 
           15}, {15, 16, 13}, {4, 2, 17}, {17, 2, 18}, {13, 16, 17}, {18, 13, 17}};
```

I am trying to find corresponding vertex order from 3d to 2d. Coordinates are different in both 3d and 2d view.  is it possible to do in mathematica?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We could do this with graph theory.  Let's turn the polygon structure into a graph:

```
g3 = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Union[Sort /@ 
  Flatten[polys /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}}, 1]]]
```

This creates a graph edge for each edge of each triangle, then filters it down to unique edges.

For the 2D we need to first join the ends.  Let's visually see which one is which:

```
Graphics[Text[#2, Reverse@#1] &~MapIndexed~uv]
```

[image: vertices]

We can now identify some vertices and make another graph:

```
npolyswrap = npolys /. {12 -> 15, 11 -> 14};

g2 = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Union[Sort /@ 
  Flatten[npolyswrap /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}}, 1]]]
```

[image: graphs]

Now find a mapping between the two graphs:

```
FindGraphIsomorphism[g2, g3]

(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 6, 4 -> 1, 17 -> 15, 18 -> 16, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 7,
    9 -> 10, 10 -> 9, 14 -> 12, 15 -> 11, 13 -> 14, 16 -> 13} *)
```

[image: animate]

Comment: LOL - Could be a hit even on YouTube :)

Comment: +1 btw the `First@# \[UndirectedEdge] Last@# & /@` bit could be replaced by `UndirectedEdge @@@`.

Comment: @Aky Good point.  Makes it look a bit nicer.

Comment: The gif is hurting my brain! p.s. very nice solution :)