# Faces and NetFaces relation in polyhedron

Tags: graphics, polyhedra

I'm trying to generate some plots of polyhedra with coloured faces. To determine the colours, I require the adjacency information of the faces. For the 3D plot this works really well. Say I want to colour the neighbours of a given face:

```
adjacency = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "AdjacentFaceIndices"]];

neighbor[f_] := Select[VertexList[adjacency], GraphDistance[adjacency, f, #] == 1 &]

live = Table[MemberQ[neighbor@1, i], {i, 20}]

Graphics3D[
 PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"] /. 
  Polygon[l_] :> 
   MapIndexed[ {Glow@@If[live[[#2[[1]]]], Black, White], Polygon[#]} &, l],
 Lighting -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

This works because the face indices used by `AdjacencyFaceIndices` are in the same order as faces returned by `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"]`. However, this does not seem to be the case for `"NetFaces"`:

```
Graphics[
 PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "NetFaces"] /. 
  Polygon[l_] :> 
   MapIndexed[{EdgeForm@Black, If[live[[#2[[1]]]], Black, White], Polygon[#]} &, l]
]
```

[image]

Is there any way to find a valid mapping of positions in `"NetFaces"` to face indices, such that I can create a net of my coloured polyhedron? Of course, this mapping is not unique, but any valid mapping would do.

It might be useful to note that this is reproducible with something as simple as a cube, but I've used an icosahedron so I could fit all the coloured faces into the 3D plot as well.

Comment: Just found a related but easier problem: [51999](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51999/5478)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Edit:** Recently Szabolcs released the new version of IGraphM (v0.2.0). Now the code below works pretty fine.

Let us imagine that we move polyhedron faces a bit:

```
name = "Icosahedron";
{poly, net} = PolyhedronData[name, {"Faces", "NetFaces"}];

Graphics3D[Normal@poly /. 
  Polygon@pts_ :> Polygon@Transpose[.9 Transpose@pts + .1 Mean@pts]]
```

[image]

Now we can construct a graph in the following way: each face corresponds to a triangle fan (gray lines below). The center vertex in the fan marks the face (black points). Initial faces have common vertices. They are marked by complete subgraphs (orange lines). We can construct this graph for the polyhedron and the net as well.

```
ids[p_] := FirstCase[p, _Polygon][[1]];
graph[p_] := Graph[#, VertexStyle -> _Integer -> Black] &@Flatten[{
       Style[UndirectedEdge@##, Orange] & @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
        GatherBy[Catenate@#, First],
       Style[UndirectedEdge@##, Darker@Gray] & @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ #,
       Style[UndirectedEdge[{##}, #2], Darker@Gray] & @@@ # & /@ #
       }] &@MapIndexed[Thread@{#1, #2[[1]]} &, ids@p];
{netG, polyG} = graph /@ {net, poly};
{netCol, polyCol} = VertexList /@ {netG, polyG} /. {_Integer -> 1, {__Integer} -> 2};

netG
```

[image]

```
Graph3D[polyG, ViewAngle -> 0.3]
```

[image]

One can see that the first graph is the subgraph of the second one. We can find the subgraph isomorphism with [`IGraphM`](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) package (thanks to Szabolcs and Kuba). If you don't have this package you can use [this comprehensive list](https://gist.github.com/ybeltukov/573c554d1cf4559b7543) of definitions.

```
<< IGraphM`;

subisomorphism = First@Normal@
  IGLADGetSubisomorphism[{netG, VertexColors -> netCol}, {polyG, 
    VertexColors -> polyCol}];
```

The following list is the face-to-face correspondence (*bijection*, similar to Kuba's `fromNet`):

```
netToPoly[name, "Faces"] = Cases[#, _@__Integer] &@subisomorphism
(* {1 -> 1, 2 -> 12, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 15, 6 -> 14, 7 -> 18, 8 -> 7, 
 9 -> 11, 10 -> 9, 11 -> 2, 12 -> 20, 13 -> 4, 14 -> 13, 15 -> 17, 16 -> 16, 
 17 -> 8, 18 -> 6, 19 -> 19, 20 -> 10} *)
```

The following list is the vertex-to-vertex correspondence. Note, that several vertices of the net can correspond to one vertex of the polyhedron (it is *surjection*):

```
netToPoly[name, "Vertices"] = 
 Union@DeleteCases[#, _@__Integer][[;; , ;; , 1]] &@subisomorphism
(* {1 -> 12, 2 -> 12, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 12, 5 -> 12, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 4, 
 9 -> 6, 10 -> 10, 11 -> 8, 12 -> 3, 13 -> 7, 14 -> 11, 15 -> 5, 16 -> 1, 17 -> 3, 
 18 -> 9, 19 -> 9, 20 -> 9, 21 -> 9, 22 -> 9} *)
```

There are nice color visualizations of such a map in other answers. Let me do something new (see code below):

[image]

Firstly, I produce graphs of connected faces

```
faceGraph[g_Graph] := 
  Graph@Cases[Tally@Cases[EdgeList@g, _[{_, i_}, {_, j_}] :> {i, j}], 
   {e_, 2} :> e];

netFG = faceGraph@netG;
polyFG = Graph[EdgeList@faceGraph@polyG /. Reverse /@ netToPoly[name, "Faces"]];
root = Last@GraphCenter@netFG;
{Graph[netFG, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  Graph[polyFG, VertexLabels -> "Name"]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Then, I do some geometry which is similar to skeletal animation in computer graphics

```
net3D = MapAt[N@# /. {p__Real} :> {p, 0.} &, net, 1];
netFaces = Flatten@N@Normal@net3D;
polyFaces = Flatten[N@Normal@poly][[Sort[netToPoly[name, "Faces"]][[;; , 2]]]];

children = GroupBy[
   DeleteCases[Thread[DepthFirstScan[netFG, root] -> VertexList@netFG], 
    root -> root], First -> Last];

ClearAll[fold, rotate, anchor]
polyVertexIDs[fID_] := ids[poly][[fID /. netToPoly[name, "Faces"]]];
commonNetVertexIDs[fID1_, fID2_] := 
  ids[net][[fID1]] ⋂ ids[net][[fID2]];
commonPolyVertexIDs[fID1_, fID2_] := 
  commonNetVertexIDs[fID1, fID2] /. netToPoly[name, "Vertices"];
anchor[fID1_, fID2_] := 
  Sequence @@ {#2 - #, #} & @@ net3D[[1, commonNetVertexIDs[fID1, fID2]]];
maxAngle[fID1_, fID2_] := 
  ArcTan[Cross[#2, #].Cross[#, #3], #.Cross@##2] &[
       Normalize[#2 - #], #3 - #, #4 - #] & @@ 
     N@poly[[1, {#[[1]], #[[2]], Complement[polyVertexIDs@fID1, #][[1]], 
        Complement[polyVertexIDs@fID2, #][[1]]}]] &@
   commonPolyVertexIDs[fID1, fID2];
rotate[parentID_, childID_, t_] := 
  GeometricTransformation[fold[t, childID], 
   RotationTransform[t maxAngle[parentID, childID], anchor[parentID, childID]]];
fold[t_, id_: root] := {netFaces[[id]], 
     If[Head@# === Missing, {}, rotate[id, #, t] & /@ #]} &@children@id;

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[fold[t], 
  PlotRange -> {MinMax@net[[1, ;; , 1]], MinMax@net[[1, ;; , 2]], {-0.5, 2.5}}, 
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 700, ViewVector -> {0, -100, 30}], {t, -1, 1}]
```

The same for `"RhombicHexecontahedron"`:

[image]

Comment: You have to help me :P Why "extended" vertex subgraph has a unique placement there? The solution is already amazing but I will appreciate it more when I fully get it :P

Comment: @Kuba The extended graph has two types of edges: edges of faces and additional "bonds" between vertices (see updated pictures). In the case of the colored graph, the unique placement is quite natural because the folding is unique (up to some symmetry group). `IGLADGetSubisomorphism` does not use edge styles. However, I think only the tetrahedron can be a problematic case.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I'm giving this the bounty because it works without manual fiddling and for an arbitrary net. @Kuba Thank you (and Dr. belisarius but I can't ping him here) for all the hard work as well. All four solutions are very interesting (and probably the best I've ever received anywhere on the SE network). I would probably give you a bounty as well if I didn't have to double the bounty amount to do so. :)

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you help me a bit? `IGLADGetSubisomorphism` for the colored graph gives me `LibraryFunction::cfct: Number of arguments 4 does not match the length 3 of the argument template. >>` At the same time `First@IGLADFindSubisomorphisms` works fine. I'm not sure, may be I use it wrong or there is a small bug in the package. Thanks again for `IGraphM`.

Comment: @ybeltukov Szabolcs won't be notified by your comment since he hasn't participated in this thread. Please ping him in chat; he's usually lurking in there or checks the transcript.

Comment: @R.M. Thank you, it was not obvious for me.

Comment: How crazy this answer is..

Answer (score 29):

#### Intro

This is completely different approach, since what we know about the net is not enough and the relation between faces and net faces isn't included, **let's create the net from the polyhedron**.

The only issue with the present code is that the net is generated automatically and doesn't have to be the same as the one in `PolyhedronData`.

**The idea** is to *unwrap* the polyhedron. We take a path through all faces and rotate faces that are left to the plane of the first one.

[image]

#### Example

```
polyhedron = "SnubCube";

selectedFace = 3;
g = Graph@PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "AdjacentFaceIndices"];

neighbors = Rest@VertexList@NeighborhoodGraph[g, selectedFace]
```

> {4, 8, 33}

```
Graphics3D[
   GraphicsComplex[
    PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "VertexCoordinates"],
    {
     White, Polygon[#],
     Red, Polygon[#[[selectedFace]]],
     Orange, Polygon[#[[neighbors]]]
     }
    ], Lighting -> "Neutral"
] & @ PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "FaceIndices"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{
    EdgeForm@Thin, White, Polygon@#,
    Red, Polygon@#[[selectedFace]],
    Orange, Polygon@#[[neighbors]]
}] & @ generateNet[polyhedron]
```

[image]

#### Code

The code is based on [**Random polyhedra walk**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79546/5478)

```
generateNet[polyhedron_] := 
 Module[{adjacencyGraph, path, coordinates, polys, result, init, 
   trans, bottomFace, nextFace, pivotEdge}
  ,
  adjacencyGraph = 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ 
     PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "AdjacentFaceIndices"] // Graph;
  path = Partition[FindShortestTour[adjacencyGraph][[2]], 2, 1];
  coordinates = N@PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "VertexCoordinates"];
  polys = PolyhedronData[polyhedron, "FaceIndices"];
  
  result = <||>;
  init = RotationTransform[
      {Cross[#2 - #, #3 - #2] & @@ #, {0, 0, 1}},
      Mean@#
      ] &@coordinates[[polys[[path[[1, 1]]]]]];
  
  coordinates = init /@ coordinates;
  (result[#] = Part[coordinates, polys[[#]]]) &@path[[1, 1]];
  Do[
   If[
    Not@MemberQ[Keys@result, path[[step, 2]]]
    ,
    
    {bottomFace, nextFace} = path[[step]];
    
    pivotEdge = Intersection @@ polys[[{bottomFace, nextFace}]];
    
    trans = polygonTransformation[
      Part[coordinates, polys[[bottomFace]]],
      Part[coordinates, polys[[nextFace]]],
      Part[coordinates, pivotEdge]
      ];
    
    coordinates = trans /@ coordinates;
    (result[#] = Part[coordinates, polys[[#]]]) &@path[[step, 2]];
    
    ],
   {step, Length[path] - 1}
   ];

  Sort[Normal@result][[;; , 2, ;; , ;; 2]]
];



polygonTransformation[coor1_, coor2_, commonEdge_] := Module[{
   normal1, normal2, angle
   },
  
  {normal1, normal2} = Function[{c1, c12, pivotV, c2},
     {Cross[c1 - c12, c12 - pivotV],
      Cross[pivotV - c12, c12 - c2]}
     ][
    Mean@coor1, Mean@commonEdge, First@commonEdge, Mean@coor2
    ];
  angle = VectorAngle @@ ({normal1, normal2});
  
  RotationTransform[angle , {normal2, normal1}, Mean@commonEdge]
  ]
```

Comment: But not every "walk" gives you a nice non-self-intersecting net http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Unfolding.html

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Thanks for the link. I was suspecting that and going to address it next time I found more time. But I wasn't worried because I wasn't expected this can be a problem in such simple cases :-/ My initial thought was, it will only be a problem for non convex polyhedra. p.s. Nice answer, I like knowledge hub - like posts like yours.

Answer (score 22):

**TL;DR;** The mapping from "Icosahedron" faces' indices to net faces' indices is given by:

```
{9 -> 10, 19 -> 20, 8 -> 19, 10 -> 17, 7 -> 9, 20 -> 8, 12 -> 18, 
 13 -> 15, 6 -> 7, 3 -> 6, 2 -> 16, 4 -> 13, 16 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 1 -> 14,
 15 -> 11, 14 -> 3, 18 -> 2, 11 -> 12, 17 -> 1}
```

but the answer isn't fully automatic, though imo worth sharing.

**The idea** is to find a subgraph in polyhedron faces adjacency graph generated by net faces adjacency graph.

**The problem** is that usually such relation isn't unique so we have to play with the input for `IGLADGetSubisomorphism` till we find the solution.

(*the net contains full information but one would have to have a procedure of assembling the polyhedron from the net to know what are all neighbors of edge faces*)

---

We will need additional function:

- `IGLADGetSubisomorphism` by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) from his great package [IGraphM](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM)

---

```
netFacesAdjacencyGraph = AdjacencyGraph@Outer[
 Boole[Length[Intersection[##]] == 2] &,
 #, #
 , 1] &@PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "NetFaceIndices"];


polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph = Graph[
    UndirectedEdge @@@ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "AdjacentFaceIndices"]
];
```

[image]

So we have to fit the left one inside the right one.

```
<< IGraphM`

fromNet = Normal @ First @ IGLADGetSubisomorphism[
    netFacesAdjacencyGraph, 
    polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph
]
```

> {1 -> 9, 2 -> 11, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 12, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 15, 8 -> 14, 
>    9 -> 10, 10 -> 7, 11 -> 19, 12 -> 18, 13 -> 2, 14 -> 20, 15 -> 4, 
>    16 -> 13, 17 -> 17, 18 -> 16, 19 -> 6, 20 -> 8}

Done :P

```
HighlightGraph[
   polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph, 
   Style[
       EdgeList[netFacesAdjacencyGraph] /. fromNet, 
       Blue, Thickness@.01
   ]
]
```

[image]

---

That's it. Now, let's just grab reversed relation:

```
toNet = Reverse /@ fromNet;

selectedInPoly = 13;

neighborsInPoly = Rest @ VertexList @ NeighborhoodGraph[
    polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph,
    selectedInPoly
]

faces = First @ Normal @ N @ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"];
netFaces = First@Normal@PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "NetFaces"];

Graphics3D[  Table[ {Which[
    i === selectedInPoly, Red,
    MemberQ[neighborsInPoly, i], Orange,
    True, White],
   faces[[i]], Black, Inset[i, 1.1 Mean@faces[[i, 1]]]
   },
  {i, Length@faces}  ],
 Lighting -> "Neutral" ] 

Graphics[ Table[ {
   EdgeForm@Black,
   Which[
    (i) === (selectedInPoly /. toNet), Red,
    MemberQ[neighborsInPoly /. toNet, i], Orange,
    True, White ],
   netFaces[[i]], Black, Inset[Text[(i /. fromNet)], Mean@netFaces[[i, 1]]]
   },
  {i, Length@netFaces} ] ]
```

[image]

So, as we can see on the right example, this isn't the transformation we were after, `15` should be in place of `20`.

**Manual adjustments** - if we reverse edge list in `polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph`, then it gives the correct transformation:

```
fromNet =  Normal @ First @ IGLADGetSubisomorphism[
   Graph @ Reverse @ EdgeList @ netFacesAdjacencyGraph, 
   polyhedronFacesAdjacencyGraph
]
```

[image]

but I don't know how to include the procedure to find proper neighbors of edge faces :-/

Comment: +1, I appreciate your idea! The problem is because the graph has no information how facets attach each other. I think it is possible to use a more complex graph like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c47OU.png). Unfortunately, I have no time to implement it.

Comment: @ybeltukov thanks, I hope you will have more time in near future, your tip didn't help me to fix it so I'm looking forward to seeing your approach :) Have a nice week.

Comment: @ybeltukov Do you think you'll be able to turn this into an answer before the bounty deadline? :)

Answer (score 20):

[**Komei Fukuda**](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/) researched the problem and developed a few nice software packages to address it and optimise the computation complexity. This answer uses Fukuda's codebase.

Just to help understanding the non-triviality of the problem, [here](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/unfold_home/unfold_open.html) are a few simple but pathological cases and the debunking of two conjectures:

- Is every unfolding of a convex polytope non-selfoverlapping?
- Is every unfolding of a convex polytope unambiguous?

[Here](ftp://ftp.ifor.math.ethz.ch/pub/fukuda/reports/) are all Fukuda's papers about the matter, paywall-free

---

To install Fukuda's packages:

1. Download (or make) the [cddml lib](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/download/cdd/cddlibml_binary/) for your machine. I used the [win32 newlib](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/download/cdd/cddlibml_binary/old/cddml_w32new.exe)
2. Download the [UnfoldPolytope2 package](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/download/mathematica/Polyhedra/)

Edit the package and change the main function to colorize the faces:

```
UnfoldPolytope[facets_List,s_Integer]:=
    Block[{odfacets,circfacets,edg,faAdj,vertices,veAdj,
    t,tree,cotree,sptree,i,tr,vervec},
    odfacets = facets;
    {edg,faAdj} = MakeEdgesFromFacets[odfacets];
    vertices = Union[Flatten[facets,1]];
    veAdj = Flatten[{Position[vertices,#[[1]]], Position[vertices,#[[2]]]}]& /@ edg;
    t = BreadthFirstSearch[MakeAdjTable[Length[vertices],veAdj],1];
    tree = Flatten[Position[veAdj,#]& /@ Position[t,1]];
    cotree = Complement[Table[i,{i,1,Length[edg]}],tree];
    sptree = MakeAdjTable[Length[odfacets],faAdj[[cotree]]];
    tr = Table[{i},{i,Length[facets]}];
    vervec = VerticalVector[odfacets];
    Do[{sptree,tr,odfacets,vervec} = Unfold[sptree,tr,N[odfacets],vervec];
       ,{i,1,Length[odfacets]-1}];
    Graphics3D[({If[MemberQ[faAdj,Sort[{s,#}]],Red,
                                  If[s==#,Yellow,Green]], 
                     Polygon[odfacets[[#]]]}&/@Range@Length@odfacets)]
    ]
```

Get the SnubCube (or any other polyhedron) description in the format required by Fukuda's code and run it.

```
cddml = Install["c:\\Downloads\\cddml_w32new"]
<< "c:\\Downloads\\UnfoldPolytope2.m"

inedata = -Flatten /@ (CoefficientArrays[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ ((List @@@ 
             PolyhedronData["SnubCube", "RegionFunction"])[x, y, z] /. 
             GreaterEqual[x__, y__] :> LessEqual[-x + y, 0] /. 
             LessEqual :> Equal)) // N;
{m, d}    = Dimensions@inedata;
{{extlist, linearity}, ecdlist, eadlist, icdlist0, iadlist0} = 
                               AllVerticesWithAdjacency[m, d, Flatten@inedata];
icdlist   = Most@icdlist0;
vlist     = Rest /@ extlist;
facets    = (vlist[[#1]] &) /@ icdlist;
facets1   = OrderFacets[facets];

t = UnfoldPolytope[facets1, #] & /@ Range@Length@facets1;
Export["c:\\test.gif", t, "DisplayDurations" -> 2];

Uninstall[cddml]
```

[image]