# Unfolding a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I wanted to know how unfolding a Polyhedron in Mathematica works. I can't seem to make it work even when I have all the coordinates I need.

The Polyhedron of reference is

```
PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron"]`
```

and I used the coordinates taken from

```
PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "NetCoordinates"]`
```

Comment: What do you mean "how unfolding... works"?  What would constitute an answer for you?

Comment: Is there something you need that this topic does not cover: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103598/5478?

Answer (score 6):

```
PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "Net"]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I'm actually running the 11th version of Mathematica, so I don't have that function. Anyway, what if I wanted to make an animation where the Polyhedron folds and unfolds by using a slider (Like a manipulate)?

Comment: @MattiaRugna:  I'm running v. 11.0.  What happens when you run this code?  And an animation wasn't what your question asked.

Comment: It actually gives me an error.

Comment: Yeah,the animation is something else connected to it Hahaha