# How to make C60 football model

Tags: dynamic, animation, polyhedra

I saw a beautiful C60 football model [here](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MjM5MzMyNTY3Nw==&mid=2453105301&idx=1&sn=9cbbedb3ed03db2bb0220c6ccaf0c238&chksm=b15b7d97862cf4816b3ce499592c12b710c2d8225cd7853dbef97e7cf2dbdc612fbcfed2e697&mpshare=1&scene=23&srcid=08058s9jn9u9oRiFduCIpmKU&sharer_sharetime=1596603472138&sharer_shareid=6131f22381f02697d54ac3aa88fa7c24#rd).

[image]

I want to reproduce this animation with MMA, but I don't know how to do it. Can you give me some help?

Comment: You can adapt code from [Faces and NetFaces relation in polyhedron](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103598/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you very much for your reply. This post is very good.